# Can't access in any way dynamically generated element with Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, dom

I've been trying to modify the router SSIDs through a script made in Selenium, the problem is that I can't get any JS element that's generated by the router page. I've been trying with the Expected Conditions and whatever you could think of but without success.

Example of commands that I used:

```py
element: WebElement = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
```

I investigated further by trying to do some queries with JavaScript in the Chrome's "Console" tab.
What I found is that if I try to select any element using any query selector before inspecting any element on the page it won't work.

Example query:

```js
document.querySelector("#WIFIIconInfo")
```

How can I fix this weird behaviour?

EDIT:
Don't know if these are useful informations, but they are still information.
The website is built off these 2 things:

```
Web frameworks
Microsoft ASP.NET

JavaScript libraries
jQuery - 1.11.1

(Wappalyzer Output)
```

EDIT 2: I looked up into the HTML as suggested by @JeffC and found out that the `div` I wanted to click was inside the following `iframe`.

```
<iframe id="menuIframe" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" class="AspWidth" scrolling="no" overflow="hidden" src="CustomApp/mainpage.asp"></iframe>
```

His solution was indeed right.

Comment: have you tried `implicitlyWait`?

Comment: Tried it right now just to be sure and it didn't work, says that it cannot find any element with specified XPATH (which I just copied to be extra sure).

Comment: then you should save the exact html (by `driver.page_source`) and look at it, maybe the website returns absolutely unexpected data (like captcha or whatever).

Comment: if you parse multiple pages from website that visually look the same in some cases they can differ from each other in html code

Comment: Nope, the `driver.page_source` is always the same.

Comment: Please check the element isn’t inside an iframe or shadow-root element?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Also post the full error message, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. We also need the relevant HTML to be able to help you with locators.

Comment: @JeffC I can't put HTML since it's all dynamically generated from ASP.NET and JS. The code that I am using to find the element is already in the question. The code before that is just a get to the router page, credentials input and then a click on a button (which redirects me to the page where I have to locate the element I am looking for)

Comment: You can load the page in the browser, open up the dev tools, and copy the relevant bits of HTML. The code you have included is not an MCVE. If you're still unsure what an MCVE is, read the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I found is that if I try to select any element using any query selector before inspecting any element on the page it won't work.

That tells me that your desired element is inside of an IFRAME. When you inspect an element on the page, the dev tools automatically switch the context to the containing IFRAME.

Using Selenium, you will need to switch into the IFRAME, interact with whichever elements are inside the IFRAME, and then switch context back out to the main page.

We don't have any relevant HTML so here's a generic example.

```
# wait for the IFRAME and switch to it
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe")))
# do stuff to elements in the IFRAME
...
# switch back to the main content of the page
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```